# owncloud client ver3.6.2 on iPad pro cannot connect to owncloud 10 server. "it is not possible to connect to the server at this time"

Tags: owncloud

i have owncloud 10.0.3 ubuntu 17.04 server.
I can access it fine from multiple desktops  using multiple users thru web browsers and thru the owncloud desktop clients on windows 10.

I have used the iPad client app before without any issues, but after my recent upgrade to owncloud 10 from OC9, and ubuntu 17.04 from 16.04, i am getting this error:

```
"it is not possible to connect to the server at this time"
```

But i am connected thru safari and able to view files there.
I checked the owncloud.log in the data dir on the server and i find this error for every login attempt i make form the ipad pro,  that i cannot begin to understand:

```
{"reqId":"MmqeK5EOQJtmVTbNvSgj","level":4,"time":"2017-10-24T10:54:19-07:00","remoteAddr":"174.215.4.61","user":"fawzi","app":"webdav","method":"PROPFIND","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/","message":"Exception: {\"Message\":\"An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM `oc_properties` WHERE `fileid` IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) AND `propertyname` in (?, ?) ORDER BY `propertyname`' with params [\\\"28343\\\", \\\"23\\\", \\\"28346\\\", \\\"47571\\\", \\\"565\\\", \\\"28345\\\", \\\"46900\\\", \\\"46852\\\", \\\"46875\\\", \\\"46991\\\", \\\"46924\\\", \\\"46988\\\", \\\"46997\\\", \\\"47055\\\", \\\"47065\\\", \\\"47075\\\", \\\"47097\\\", \\\"28323\\\", \\\"28320\\\", \\\"47202\\\", \\\"47206\\\", \\\"47207\\\", \\\"47147\\\", \\\"21\\\", \\\"31235\\\", \\\"25\\\", \\\"47597\\\", \\\"2123\\\", \\\"47573\\\", \\\"2126\\\", \\\"47643\\\", \\\"2125\\\", \\\"47168\\\", \\\"36885\\\", \\\"24\\\", \\\"28648\\\", \\\"648\\\", \\\"31236\\\", \\\"2448\\\", \\\"2449\\\", \\\"28291\\\", \\\"31230\\\", \\\"3179\\\", \\\"3180\\\", \\\"16\\\", \\\"2479\\\", \\\"47651\\\", \\\"47572\\\", \\\"3370\\\", \\\"36859\\\", \\\"28649\\\", 31202, \\\"{DAV:}creationdate\\\", \\\"{DAV:}displayname\\\"]:\\n\\nSQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fileid' in 'where clause'\",\"Exception\":\"Doctrine\\\\DBAL\\\\Exception\\\\InvalidFieldNameException\",\"Code\":0,\"Trace\":\"#0 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/doctrine\\\/dbal\\\/lib\\\/Doctrine\\\/DBAL\\\/DBALException.php(128): Doctrine\\\\DBAL\\\\Driver\\\\AbstractMySQLDriver->convertException('An exception oc...', Object(Doctrine\\\\DBAL\\\\Driver\\\\PDOException))\\n#1 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/doctrine\\\/dbal\\\/lib\\\/Doctrine\\\/DBAL\\\/Connection.php(855): Doctrine\\\\DBAL\\\\DBALException::driverExceptionDuringQuery(Object(Doctrine\\\\DBAL\\\\Driver\\\\PDOMySql\\\\Driver), Object(Doctrine\\\\DBAL\\\\Driver\\\\PDOException), 'SELECT * FROM `...', Array)\\n#2 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/private\\\/DB\\\/Connection.php(190): Doctrine\\\\DBAL\\\\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM `...', Array, Array, NULL)\\n#3 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/apps\\\/dav\\\/lib\\\/Connector\\\/Sabre\\\/CustomPropertiesBackend.php(333): OC\\\\DB\\\\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM `...', Array, Array)\\n#4 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/apps\\\/dav\\\/lib\\\/Connector\\\/Sabre\\\/CustomPropertiesBackend.php(139): OCA\\\\DAV\\\\Connector\\\\Sabre\\\\CustomPropertiesBackend->loadChildrenProperties(Object(OCA\\\\DAV\\\\Connector\\\\Sabre\\\\Directory), Array)\\n#5 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/sabre\\\/dav\\\/lib\\\/DAV\\\/PropertyStorage\\\/Plugin.php(91): OCA\\\\DAV\\\\Connector\\\\Sabre\\\\CustomPropertiesBackend->propFind('', Object(Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\PropFind))\\n#6 [internal function]: Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\PropertyStorage\\\\Plugin->propFind(Object(Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\PropFind), Object(OCA\\\\DAV\\\\Connector\\\\Sabre\\\\Directory))\\n#7 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/sabre\\\/event\\\/lib\\\/EventEmitterTrait.php(105): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\\n#8 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/sabre\\\/dav\\\/lib\\\/DAV\\\/Server.php(1058): Sabre\\\\Event\\\\EventEmitter->emit('propFind', Array)\\n#9 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/sabre\\\/dav\\\/lib\\\/DAV\\\/Server.php(980): Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\Server->getPropertiesByNode(Object(Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\PropFind), Object(OCA\\\\DAV\\\\Connector\\\\Sabre\\\\Directory))\\n#10 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/sabre\\\/dav\\\/lib\\\/DAV\\\/Server.php(1665): Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\Server->getPropertiesIteratorForPath('', Array, 1)\\n#11 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/sabre\\\/dav\\\/lib\\\/DAV\\\/CorePlugin.php(355): Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\Server->generateMultiStatus(Object(Generator), false)\\n#12 [internal function]: Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\CorePlugin->httpPropFind(Object(Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Request), Object(Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Response))\\n#13 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/sabre\\\/event\\\/lib\\\/EventEmitterTrait.php(105): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\\n#14 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/sabre\\\/dav\\\/lib\\\/DAV\\\/Server.php(479): Sabre\\\\Event\\\\EventEmitter->emit('method:PROPFIND', Array)\\n#15 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/sabre\\\/dav\\\/lib\\\/DAV\\\/Server.php(254): Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\Server->invokeMethod(Object(Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Request), Object(Sabre\\\\HTTP\\\\Response))\\n#16 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/apps\\\/dav\\\/appinfo\\\/v1\\\/webdav.php(63): Sabre\\\\DAV\\\\Server->exec()\\n#17 \\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/remote.php(165): require_once('\\\/var\\\/www\\\/ownclo...')\\n#18 {main}\",\"File\":\"\\\/var\\\/www\\\/owncloud\\\/lib\\\/composer\\\/doctrine\\\/dbal\\\/lib\\\/Doctrine\\\/DBAL\\\/Driver\\\/AbstractMySQLDriver.php\",\"Line\":71,\"User\":\"fawzi\"}"}
{"reqId":"YAiD9Quchf9It7tENFbS","level":3,"time":"2017-10-24T10:57:35-07:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.254","user":"fawzi","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"\/ocs\/v2.php\/apps\/notifications\/api\/v1\/notifications?format=json","message":"Undefined index: icon at \/var\/www\/owncloud\/apps\/notifications\/lib\/Handler.php#288"}
{"reqId":"YAiD9Quchf9It7tENFbS","level":3,"time":"2017-10-24T10:57:35-07:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.254","user":"fawzi","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"\/ocs\/v2.php\/apps\/notifications\/api\/v1\/notifications?format=json","message":"Undefined index: icon at \/var\/www\/owncloud\/apps\/notifications\/lib\/Handler.php#288"}
{"reqId":"YAiD9Quchf9It7tENFbS","level":3,"time":"2017-10-24T10:57:35-07:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.254","user":"fawzi","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"\/ocs\/v2.php\/apps\/notifications\/api\/v1\/notifications?format=json","message":"Undefined index: icon at \/var\/www\/owncloud\/apps\/notifications\/lib\/Handler.php#288"}
{"reqId":"YAiD9Quchf9It7tENFbS","level":3,"time":"2017-10-24T10:57:35-07:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.254","user":"fawzi","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"\/ocs\/v2.php\/apps\/notifications\/api\/v1\/notifications?format=json","message":"Undefined index: icon at \/var\/www\/owncloud\/apps\/notifications\/lib\/Handler.php#288"}
{"reqId":"pcgFnEKh1pdDjIgy1ynV","level":3,"time":"2017-10-24T11:02:35-07:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.254","user":"fawzi","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"\/ocs\/v2.php\/apps\/notifications\/api\/v1\/notifications?format=json","message":"Undefined index: icon at \/var\/www\/owncloud\/apps\/notifications\/lib\/Handler.php#288"}
{"reqId":"pcgFnEKh1pdDjIgy1ynV","level":3,"time":"2017-10-24T11:02:35-07:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.254","user":"fawzi","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"\/ocs\/v2.php\/apps\/notifications\/api\/v1\/notifications?format=json","message":"Undefined index: icon at \/var\/www\/owncloud\/apps\/notifications\/lib\/Handler.php#288"}
{"reqId":"pcgFnEKh1pdDjIgy1ynV","level":3,"time":"2017-10-24T11:02:35-07:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.254","user":"fawzi","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"\/ocs\/v2.php\/apps\/notifications\/api\/v1\/notifications?format=json","message":"Undefined index: icon at \/var\/www\/owncloud\/apps\/notifications\/lib\/Handler.php#288"}
{"reqId":"pcgFnEKh1pdDjIgy1ynV","level":3,"time":"2017-10-24T11:02:35-07:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.1.254","user":"fawzi","app":"PHP","method":"GET","url":"\/ocs\/v2.php\/apps\/notifications\/api\/v1\/notifications?format=json","message":"Undefined index: icon at \/var\/www\/owncloud\/apps\/notifications\/lib\/Handler.php#288"}
```

any idea on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Your installations is probably broken. There is something in your database which shouldn't be there. I think you have two options. Truncate the oc_properties table. But you will probably lose data because there is other important information in it. Or you try to migrate to Nextcloud which cleans up the DB in the process. At least this is what it did for me.
Nextcloud has less bugs anyways. 
I hope this helps.

Comment: that's pretty much what i did, but with owncloud 10. Reinstalling it did the trick.  i rescaned for files and everything was back in place.  I don't know much about nextcloud, but i will take a look at it... thanks